# Programmatically add ToolStrip menu items

Tags: vb.net, toolstripmenu

How to add ToolStrip menu items programmatically?

Comment: MSDN How to: Add ToolStrip Items Dynamically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229625(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

here is the code...
for adding non-toolstrip default controls..
    Dim StripHost1 As New ToolStripControlHost(button1)
    ToolStrip1.Items.Add(StripHost1)

for adding toolstrip menu items (defaults, allowed at design time also)..

```
Friend WithEvents myToolStripButton As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton
Me.myToolStripButton = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton
Me.MainToolStrip.Items.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem() {Me.myToolStripButton})
```

Comment: The OP was looking for menu items, not buttons in a ToolStripControlHost.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me as all I wanted was to achieve a toolstrip generated text.

> ```
> Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
>     Dim NEOitem As String = TextBox6.Text
>     ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(NEOitem)
> End Sub
> ```